# Could anyone explain what's wrong with my regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a question with a small regex. In a sentence, I would like to match one or many words and the only characters allowed before and after, is an optional space character.

E.g: in the sentence `Ut volutpat egestas volutpat.` I would like to match `volutpat` and not `volutpat.` unless I'm looking for `volutpat.` specifically.

Here is the code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhCcL/)):

```
var sentence = 'Ut volutpat egestas volutpat.',
    word = 'volutpat',
    regex = new RegExp('[\s]?' + word + '[\s]?', 'g');

console.log(sentence.match(regex));
```

Unfortunately in the console, that code above returns two matches:

```
[ "volutpat", "volutpat" ]
```

Please note that, `word = 'volutpat egestas'` or `word = 'volutpat.'` must works too if I have to match them.

Comment: I don't want to match the second word because it has a `.` after and I'm not looking for `volutpat.` but `volutpat`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When building regular expressions dynamically, you need to keep in mind that any backslashes need to be escaped again:

```
var sentence = 'Ut volutpat egestas volutpat.',
    word = 'volutpat',
    regex = new RegExp('[\\s]?' + word + '[\\s]?', 'g');
```

Also, you probably want to check for space-or-start-or-end, not space-optionally, so:

```
var sentence = 'Ut volutpat egestas volutpat.',
    word = 'volutpat',
    regex = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + word + '(\\s|$)', 'g');
```

Assuming `word` won’t come escaped, you might also want to look into [escaping that, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2593637/707111).

Comment: This works great. On freenode, I have been suggested to use `\b`. If I do, both words are still matched. Any reason why? Is that a missuse of \b?

Comment: @Cybrix: That’s generally what you would use to match a whole word (it means “word boundary”), but a period is still a word boundary so it doesn’t work completely in your particular case.

Comment: I'm using the code found in your second example. I find one problem that I haven't noticed but it breaks my HTML when I try it. It does indeed match `volutpat` but it does it with the space characters. Or can I avoid this?

Comment: @Cybrix: Are you trying to use it in a replacement, or…?

Comment: Yes. It is later used in a `string.replace(regex, fn)` that "highlight" the words by wrapping it with a `<span>`.

Comment: @Cybrix: What arguments does `fn` accept? Just get it to prepend and append its second and third arguments, respectively, if they’re not `null`.

Comment: For now, my `fn` only has one argument which is the matched word. I am not sure what the additional args could provide.

Comment: @Cybrix: Groups, which `(^|\s)` and `(\s|$)` are. For example, if you had `function fn(match) { return doSomething(match); }` then it would become `function fn(match, before, after) { return (before || '') + doSomething(match) + (after || ''); }`.

Answer (score 1):

You want the edges to match *either* a space character, or the start/end of a line. So:

```
(\s|^)(volutpat)(\s|$)
```

This should work even if the search word itself contains a dot. Here it is [in action](http://www.debuggex.com/r/5BtYgmjC1-McEx3A/0).

Answer (score 1):

That's because you specified the space as optional, hence it will match also entities with no boundaries or boundaries other than the space.

In the sentence you specified the word appears twice, the first matches with the spaces, the second matches the word by itself (without any spaces around it).

Answer (score 0):

Any special characters you type into `word` will be treated as such unless they are escaped by a backslash `\`. The example you have provided will match 2 times because there are two words that match.